# XPath - test if at least one node has given value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Given the following XML:

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
        <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

I would like to check if at least one node has year of for example '1982'. Something like:

```
<xsl:if test="........" ><p>passed!</p></xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In both XPath 1.0 and Xpath 2.0**:

```
'1982' = /catalog/cd/year
```

**Variations**:

XPath 1.0:

```
1982 = /catalog/cd/year
```

XPath 2.0:

```
1982 = /catalog/cd/year/number()
```

**[The XPath `=` operator](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-general-comparisons)** is very powerful when at least one of its arguments is a node-set (or a sequence in XPath 2.0). The result is true if and only if the (atomized)value of at least one of the nodes in the node-set (sequence) is equal to the other argument of `=`. This is exactly what this question is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try test="index-of(/catalog/cd/year, 1982)".

Comment: Thanks I also got it with: `test="catalog/cd/year[contains(.,'1982')]"`

Comment: @VoodooRider: `contains()` isn't what you want -- you want test for equality.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
/catalog/cd/year = 1982
```

This comparison (called general comparison) operator returns true if at least one item on the left side "matches" one item on the right side.