# If condition with and without the square brackets XSLT

Tags: xpath, xslt

I am learning XSLT and I came to an aspect of XSLT/XPath which is not clear to me.

I want to check if there is at least one element `namePart` with a value inside.

There can be something like this in XML:

```
<mods:name type="personal">
      <mods:namePart type="family">Salamonis</mods:namePart>
      <mods:namePart type="given"/>
</mods:name>
```

But also this due to any reason:

```
<mods:name type="personal">
      <mods:namePart/>
</mods:name>
```

I think I have found out the solution for my problem. Actually I found two similar solutions but I do not understand the difference:

first:

```
<xsl:for-each select="mods:name">
                 <xsl:if test="mods:namePart/text() != ''"> ..... </xsl:if>
<xsl:for-each>
```

second:

```
<xsl:for-each select="mods:name">
                 <xsl:if test="mods:namePart[text() != '']"> ..... </xsl:if>
<xsl:for-each>
```

Apparently, both of them are working fine. But I am still thinking what is better to use or if there are some minor differences.
My solution is taken from this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7660915/14163073
So are both of these solution working in accordance with the comment? (*operator returns true if at least one item on the left side "matches" one item on the right side*)

Thanks for any explanation!

Comment: You can't have empty text nodes (at least not by parsing lexical XML input) so you could as well check e.g. `<xsl:if test="mods:namePart/text()">`. The main point is that in a boolean context like the `test` expression of an `xsl:if` is to understand that an empty node(set in XPath 1, sequence in XPath 2 and later) evaluates to false while an non-empty node-set/sequence evaluates to true. On the other hand, if the sole context of your `xsl:for-each` is that `xsl:if`, I would suggest to shorten that to `<xsl:for-each select="mods:name[mods:namePart/text()]">..</xsl:for-each>`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. If I expand my question, let's say, I want to check for specific value in the elements within if statement. Is it better to use this  `<xsl:if test="mods:namePart[text() = 'foo']">` or this  `<xsl:if test="mods:namePart/text() = 'foo'">`. The thing is when to use brackets and when slash? Or is it right simply to use `<xsl:if test="price='foo'">`. Maybe it doesn't matter .. I would like to learn XSLT correctly from the beginning.. Is there some preferable way?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, take a tour through an XPath tutorial, I would say. Preferences are often a personal choice and style. For the last test I would simply use e.g. `<xsl:if test="mods:namePart = 'foo'">` as that works for any contents of the `mods:namePart` elements. It doesn't really matter for your simple example but in the end you might end up using XPath against e.g. some mixed contents HTML paragraph element and want to check its whole content (e.g. `test="p = 'This is an example text.'"`) and the `p` could be anything from a simple `<p>This is an example text.</p>` to `<p>This is an <b>example</b> text.</p>`.